# How to create a Debian package from a list of C object files

Tags: debian, deb

I am new to Debian packaging. I tried to get how to make a Debian package from binary objects, but every website gives me tools how to build and install an already available package. But I want to make it using a list of C binary files.

So how can I make a Debian package using libraries?

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources about Debian packaging; the foremost (but not a newbie resource) is the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/).

In so many words, you create a package by populating your source directory with `debian/control` and `debian/rules` and, depending on the contents of your `debian/rules` file, auxiliary files to build your project.  These days, the simplest way to go from start to finish is probably to run [`dh_make`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/dh_make.8.html), which will create a template for you to customize.

See also https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging and [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/)